# How to enable/disable a Service Broker queue using SMO?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2008, smo, service-broker

I am using  SMO objects to access my database. I have service broker enabled on SQL Server. I was wondering if anyone knew how to enable/disable queue's through code (VB/C#). I've tried `ServiceQueue.IsEnqueueEnabled` but this only sets the the property.

Comment: What does "only sets the property" mean? Presumably you want to set it? Do you mean that after setting the property the queue is still enabled? If so can you show your code and clarify how you know that the queue is still enabled? According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue_properties(v=sql.100).aspx) `ServiceQueue.IsEnqueueEnabled` is indeed used to set whether or not the queue is enabled so you seem to be using the correct property.

Comment: I guess I could be clearer. ServiceQueue.IsEnqueueEnabled is correct for finding out (Getting) if the queue is enabled, but I tried setting the property hoping that it would fire an event to change the queue but that was not the case.

Comment: Unfortunately without seeing code and without knowing where you are checking the queue state it's not possible to say what's happening. Can you post a short, self-contained SMO program that demonstrates your problem? If your SMO code really does nothing then you can trace it with SQL Profiler to see what TSQL commands it's executing behind the scenes; it should probably look something like Aaron's answer.

Comment: @noXpert: you should know that all SMO interactions are in memory only untill you actually apply them, ie. call [`.Alter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.alter.aspx). Only then is the server object changed, using the appropriate DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that controls the `STATUS = {ON | OFF}` is indeed [`.IsEnqueueEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.isenqueueenabled.aspx). But all SMO modifications are in-memory only until the [`.Alter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.alter.aspx) method is called:

> The Alter method updates any changes that have been made to the ServiceQueue object's properties since the ServiceQueue object was created or since the last Alter statement.

This is the general way of interacting with SMO objects, changes are in-memory only until explicitly applied.

In case your curious why the property is called `IsEnqueueEnabled` the short answer is that the name (properly) reflects the column name of [`sys.service_queues.is_enqueue_enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187795.aspx). The long asnwer is that the column is so named because once upon a time queues had the capability to be disabled separately for enqueue and for dequeue. The separation did not made the light of 2005 RTM but the traces were left in the catalog view.